# How do I get an actionLink in the navbar of a shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, navbar

I want users to click a link in the navbar and a certain action to occur (as if they clicked an actionLink or actionButton). However, it seems like the only way to add items to the navbar is to create a tabPanel. If I create a tabPanel that only contains an actionLink, a link is provided, but it is not inline with the rest of the tabPanels.

See code below for an example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(
  navbarPage(title = "This is the navbar",
             tabPanel("Tab 1"),
             tabPanel("Tab 2"),
             tabPanel(actionLink("Save_button", "Save")))
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$Save_button,{

    print("You just clicked the actionLink in the navbar")

  }) 

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As you can see, the actionLink called "Save" is visible in the navbar, but there is an empty box / space above it. If you click that space above the "Save" actionLink, then you will navigate to an empty tab. Is there a way to get rid of that empty space above the actionLink so that the actionLink is inline with the reset of the tabPanels and the user doesn't get taken to an empty tab?

Or do you know of a better way to include an actionButton or Link in the navbar?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using the `id` argument of `navbarPage` to trigger reactions after clicking a `tabPanel`. Please check the following:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(
  navbarPage(
    title = "This is the navbar",
    id = "navbarID",
    tabPanel("Tab 1"),
    tabPanel("Tab 2"),
    tabPanel("Save")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$navbarID, {
    if (input$navbarID == "Save") {
      print("You just clicked 'Save' in the navbar")
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I tried tagging you in my post below, but it didn't work. Just letting you know that this suggestion helped get me where I wanted to be. Thanks

Comment: The desired behaviour wasn't clear to me from you question.

Answer (score 1):

I took your idea, @ismirsehregal, but changed it slightly. Now when the user isn't taken to an empty tab in order to perform the action. They are immediately taken back to the previous tab, and the action is still performed.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(
  navbarPage(
    title = "This is the navbar",
    id = "navbarID",
    tabPanel("Tab 1"),
    tabPanel("Tab 2"),
    tabPanel("Save")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # initiate reactive value storage
  rv = reactiveValues()

  observeEvent(input$navbarID, {

    # store last tab
    rv$last_tab <- rv$current_tab
    rv$current_tab <- input$navbarID

    if (input$navbarID == "Save") {
      print("You just clicked 'Save' in the navbar")

      # immediately navigate back to previous tab
      updateTabsetPanel(session, "navbarID",
                        selected = rv$last_tab)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```